# XML Stored as Variable. How Can I Get an Element in the Variable by XPATH?

Tags: xml, variables, xpath

## **Problem**

Hello, I am trying to get an element by using XPATH. I have stored the XML that I fetched using the xmlHTTP.open command in the variable XML. However, I have no idea how to use XPATH to get an element in the XML that is stored inside the variable.

**Any advice?**

Here is the code:

```
var XML;
var Day;

function httpGet(location,week,day){
    var xmlHttp = null;
    Day = day;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bsd.ufl.edu%2Fdining%2FMenus%2FdinHallMenu.aspx%3Flocid%3D"+location+"%26ms%3D"+week+"%26%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&callback=", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    XML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    console.log(XML)
    getResults();
}

function getResults(){
    var getElementByXpath = function(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function which evaluates the xpath and returns a node or nodes depending on your xpath.

```
function evaluateXMLPath(expr,node){
    var retVal=new Array();
    //IE
    if(window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document"){
        try{
            retVal=node.selectNodes(expr);
        }catch(e){
            alert("IE:xpath not supported");
        }
    }
    //chrome, firefox,opera,etc.
    else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){

        try{
            var nodes=node.evaluate(expr, node, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);         
            for(var i=0;i<nodes.snapshotLength;i++){
                retVal[retVal.length]=nodes.snapshotItem(i);
            }
        }catch(ex){
            alert("Other:xpath not supported");
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

you use the above function as shown below.

```
var capNode=evaluateXMLPath("//root",xml);
var textStr = capNode[0].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

This might help. Thanks